# jquery draggable hide object instead of cloaning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

my issue is that i have box with sets of draggable objects ,
when one objects are dragged rest objects auto fits box to occupy whole area instead i want

either
1: no auto adjust when object moved
or
2: just set css hidden will solve issue

see below url

http://dev-shree.com/market/

click "candy"

now drag extreme right icon on elephat to fax you will see whole coins get resize to fix that square , how can i stopp this

```
$("#draggable1,#draggable2,#draggable3,#draggable4,#draggable5,#draggable6,#draggable7,#draggable8,#draggable9,#draggable10,#draggable11,#draggable12,#draggable13,#draggable14,#draggable15,#draggable16,#draggable17,#draggable18,#draggable19,#draggable20,#draggable21,#draggable22,#draggable23,#draggable24,#draggable25,#draggable26,#draggable27,#draggable28,#draggable29,#draggable30,#draggable31,#draggable32,#draggable33,#draggable34,#draggable35,#draggable36,#draggable37,#draggable38,#draggable39,#draggable40,#draggable41,#draggable42,#draggable43").draggable({ 
        revert:  function(dropped) {
           var dropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "feed_me";
           if(!dropped);
           return !dropped;

        } 
    }).each(function() {
        var top = $(this).position().top;
        var left = $(this).position().left;
        $(this).data('orgTop', top);
        $(this).data('orgLeft', left);
    });
```

Comment: That is a *really* huge selector. Why don't you use class based selector to start with.

Comment: ok fine will update it later , but how can i fix my issue